# Bind Android textview to firebase database field

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-asynctask

I have a textView in my activity - say, "Username". It is supposed to be populated from a Firebase database.  I am making the Firebase query in Asynctask so as not to block the activity. However that means that the TextView loads first, before the Firebase query is completely executed.

So what is the best way to refresh this textBox after the Firebase query is executed inside the AsyncTask and the username gets known?
I do not want to showprogressBar and block the activity while the data is being fetched from the database. That would defeat the purpose of doing it in AsyncTask.

Code for the AsyncTask is below

```
   private class CheckUserLoginAndRetrieveDataFromFirebase extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        if (thisAppUser!=null) {
            setUserDataForToday();  
            if (createNewNode) { //This is the first time the User is logging in
                createUsersNodesForFirstTime();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Code for my Firebase Query in the AsyncTask is below

```
public static void setUserDataForToday() {
    setProperDatabaseReference(); //This sets reference to user specific nodes in the database
    myRef.child("dashboard").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Dashboard dashboard = dataSnapshot.getValue(Dashboard.class);
            if (dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() > 0) {
                createNewNode = false;
                if (dashboard.checkIfTodaysDateExistsInDatabase()) {
                    //An entry for todays date exists in database, so no data change needed
                    myDashboard = dashboard;
                }
```

Comment: The Firebase Database client runs all network interaction off the main thread already, there is no need to use an `AsyncTask` for that. It then invokes your `onDataChange` on the main thread, so that you can update the UI.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen- Hi Frank, yes, I understand and tried that earlier but I keep getting issues with static and non-static variables and methods. Also the "context" of the activity is not available inside "onDataChange". I do not want to stop user navigating away from the activity which is retrieving "username", so I don't want to hold the context or the UI elements. But in case, he is still on that activity when the "onDataChange" is finished, I want to refresh teh appropriate UI element. What would you suggest the most efficient way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this example will help you

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setUserDataForToday();
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Process is not blocked");
    }

    public void setUserDataForToday() {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Called method");
        DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        database.child("users").child("1").child("name").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    String userName = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "Received value: " + dataSnapshot.getValue());
                    dataSnapshot.getKey();
                    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textUserName);
                    textView.setText(userName);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "DB error: " + databaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        setUserDataForToday();
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not work as onPostExecute gets called much faster than the data is retrieved from the Firebase

Comment: You are right. Firebase client loads the data in a separate thread. So AsyncTask doesn't wait it. For what reason did you made setUserDataForToday() static? You can't call non static properties from static method so you can't change UI. If you make setUserDataForToday() non static you could call it from main thread and change TextView in onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) method.

Comment: I made it static because I need to reuse the same function for another activity. So instead of writing it again, I made it static in a separate class.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Android studio click tools>Firebase>Realtime Database and follow instructions. This will get you started. You probably want to click tools>firebase>authentication if you want to have users and if you want only certain users to access certain things configure rules for the database. Frank is correct no need for async task.